# Bootstrap 3 Datepicker capture date using inline calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm trying to capture the date selected on my bootstrap 3 datepicker, but I can't seem to understand the documentation, so I tried this:

```
            <div id="datetimepicker">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="datepicker-data"></div>
            </div>
```

with my jquery being:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline:true,
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]

});

    $("#datetimepicker").click(function(){
        var dateData = $('#datepicker-data').val();
        alert(dateData);            
    });
```

How do I get the date I selected on the datepicker?

Answer (score 1):

Your html was incorrect. Here is the corrected html. I believe your intention was to use inline datetimepicker such as in [this example](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/#inline). If you see the example quoted in the page:

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <!-- Start of datetimepicker html-->
               <div id="datetimepicker12"></div>
            <!-- End of datetimepicker html-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div></code>
```

So your corrected HTML should be as belows:

```
  <div id="datetimepicker">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="datepicker-data">
  </div>
```

javascript

```
 $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
   inline:true,
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
   daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6]
 });

 $("#datetimepicker").click(function(){
    var dateData = $('#datepicker-data').val();
    alert(dateData);            
 });
```

Comment: Yes, I plan to use inline to the datepicker, but I am referring to the bootstrap 3 datetimepicker. that's why I placed the input inside the div.

Comment: I edited the answer with bootstrap3 datetimepicker example info. The example in the site did not have any input element in the div.